# What is the meaning of "Ya con hotra y como se yama mijo"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, coloquialismos

I saw the following phrase as a comment on a recent "in a relationship" announcement on Facebook:

> Ya con hotra y como se yama mijo

I'm not a Spanish speaker, and the automatic translate came up with:

> Already with hotra and how yama millet

That doesn't make much sense to me. I tried translating "hotra" and "yama" by themselves to no avail. Are these slang? Are they verbatim words from another language? Someone insinuated that the phrase was inappropriate, but didn't yield an explanation.

Comment: Could you tell us more about the insinuation that it was inappropriate?  I wonder if you might have misinterpreted that comment.  It would be a lot easier to figure out if you share that part as well.  Thanks.

Comment: @aparente001 My best guess in light of the accepted answer is that it was "inappropriate" to ask "(are you) already with another" on a public relationship announcement that friends of both parties could see. I would at least find that to be rude.

Comment: I personally find it not rude; it is merely direct.  If this is a question that anyone would ask me, for instance, it is because there is an obvious specific changing that has happened very recently in my life that would make it surprising.  Or, on the other hand, that I am flippant about relationships, and keep flitting from one to another with minimal time in between a la hookup culture.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The phrase is lacking punctuation and has multiple spelling mistakes that make it difficult to figure out. Fixing those you get something like:

> ¿Ya con otra? ¿Y cómo se llama, mi hijo?

Which can be roughly translated to:

> Already with another? And what's her name, my child?

Comment: actually, the term mijo is in the Diccionario de americanismos, and in this case could be more like male friend or partner, so the sentence will be *what's her name, dude?* (as my child could be also)

Comment: +1 because even though I'm a native Spanish speaker I had to read your answer to get the whole meaning of the original sentence. :-)

Comment: @VeAqui I would not say this is the case. In most of Mexican Spanish mijo just means son, it comes from a contraction of "Mi hijo", my son. While it's used sometimes as friend or dude, it's rare and probably more common in US Spanish, that's where I've heard it.

Comment: References for *mijo*: https://www.lexico.com/es-en/traducir/mijo#h70257377725940, https://www.lexico.com/es/definicion/mijo#h70290968322220.  I think here it could be translated as *dude* or *dear* depending on the age of the speaker, and depending on the relationship; if it's a former romantic interest, it could be a bit sarcastic, maybe *sweetheart* or *heartthrob*.

Comment: "Mijo" can also be translated in the same vein as "_bro_", depending on the microculture. More common on gym settings.

Comment: I grew up in Argentina and no one would ever use "mijo" in the sense people use "dude" and "bro" in English. Mostly because it is not used among peers, but rather by an older person when addressing a much younger person.

Answer (score 5):

**hotra** and **yama**, not slang, are misspellings of Spanish "otro(a)" meaning
"other/another" and "llama", which is 3rd person singular in the present indicative of the Spanish "llamar", meaning "to call" or "to name".

**Mijo** is millet, but in this case the term is the elided form of "mi hijo(a)"; literally "my son/daughter".

Yes, these terms are, coincidentally, words from other languages that do not apply. I hope this responds in some measure to your question.